# landscape left or right in terms of traitCollection and size classes?

Tags: ios8, ios9, landscape, size-classes, uitraitcollection

I've learned the Auto Layout, UITraitCollection and size classes to make
adaptive UI. But I understand that I'm missing one thing.

Put it simple: I want my UI stick to home button just like the native camera app
does. To do this I specify the constraints string like this "H:[view]-0-|". But
the layout of views differ if I launch the app in landscape left and right
position. So it means that the information about the size classes is not enough.
There is no such thing as landscape left or right in terms of size classes.

There is such a property as UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation. But it is
deprecated.

So how in terms of traits and size classes should I determine if the orientation
is landscape left or right, so that I can stick my views to the home button?

Answer (score 0):

Check `UIDevice.current.orientation` within the `viewWillTransitionToSize` function. Is is not deprecated.